# NLog MailTarget with bufferingwrapper and autoflushwrapper: reverse order of events?

Tags: nlog

I'm using the following structure:

```xml
    <target name="MailOnError" xsi:type="AutoFlushWrapper" condition="level >= LogLevel.Error" flushOnConditionOnly="true">
      <target name="MailBuffer" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" bufferSize="250" overflowAction="Discard">
        <-- note: mail config has been removed -->
        <target xsi:type="Mail"
              name="email"
              header="Error in ${processname}:${newline}
Machine: ${machinename}${newline}
Proces: ${processname}${newline}
User: ${environment-user}${newline}
${newline}
${newline}"
              layout="${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss}: ${message} (in ${callsite})${newline}"
              />
      </target>
```

This works almost fine to achieve my goal: receiving an e-mail on error, with the most recent log-entries embedded to have some context about the error.

It would be nice if I get the error on the top of my e-mail-message (or, even better, receive the log-entries in descending order).
How can this be done (if possible without writing my own custom target)?

Comment: I think a custom target wrapper is only the solution here. I could provide a tailored example.

Comment: @Julian Ok, can you provide me the example? Thank you.

Comment: Added as answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this:

```cs
[Target("ReverseOrderWrapper", IsWrapper = true)]
public class ReverseOrderWrapper : WrapperTargetBase
{
    protected override void Write(IList<AsyncLogEventInfo> logEvents)
    {
        // Some re oder logic
        var reorderEvents = logEvents.Reverse().ToArray();
        WrappedTarget.WriteAsyncLogEvents(reorderEvents);
    }
}
```

Register (as soon as possible), NLog 4.7+ syntax

```cs
NLog.LogManager.Setup().SetupExtensions(s =>
   s.RegisterTarget<ReverseOrderWrapper>("ReverseOrderWrapper")
);
```

Usage:

```xml
<target name="MailOnError" xsi:type="AutoFlushWrapper" condition="level >= LogLevel.Error" flushOnConditionOnly="true">
    <target name="MailBuffer" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" bufferSize="250" 
overflowAction="Discard">
        <target name="Reoder" xsi:type="ReverseOrderWrapper">
            <-- note: mail config has been removed -->
            <target xsi:type="Mail"
                name="email"
                header="Error in ${processname}:${newline}
Machine: ${machinename}${newline}
Proces: ${processname}${newline}
User: ${environment-user}${newline}
${newline}
${newline}"
                layout="${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss}: ${message} (in ${callsite})${newline}"
                />
    </target>
    </target>
</target>
```

Comment: One issue that comes up with this wrapper is that the MailTarget now has the 'first' event as 'lastEvent'. Because the events are in reversed order passed to the MailTarget, now the [lastEvent](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/2cf7f74b2a55157547f234dd110708712f947b6c/src/NLog/Targets/MailTarget.cs#L400) returns the first event.
Any solution for this (without creating my whole own MailTarget)?

Comment: Ah yes that's an issue for the header. The only solution is see for now is to duplicate the first event (before reverse) in the ReverseOrderWrapper.

Comment: That's an acceptable solution indeed, thanks for the suggestion.